# How to achieve adequate topology for irregular plane

Tags: modeling, topology

I am trying to model this component of the bed:
[image]

Here is what I have got so far in Blender:
[image]

How should I topologise that surface? Both Voxel and Quad Remesher produce undesirable effects on the edges.

Comment: Are you planning on modelling the holes?  Are you planning on modelling the groove?  Are you planning on bevelling the edges, subdividing?  Extruding and baking selected to active?  Topology for a plane-- your Blender pic-- doesn't matter.  But if it's not actually going to be a plane, then topology matters, but it depends on what your actual plans are for the shape.

Comment: I am hoping to do some bevelling along the edges once I extrude the plane so it has width.

Comment: And is that all?  You want an extruded plane with smooth shading, but no holes, no subdivision?

Comment: I'd like to get there eventually. But I'm taking it one step at a time. Right now my shading is very rough when I bevel the edges of my mesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so where you want to get, right now, is an extruded plane with a bevel.  Smooth shaded, no subdivision.  Maybe later, you'll work on the details.  I'll assume you're planning on rendering in Blender.  The plane is an arbitrary shape, concave:

[image]

Looks terrible right after extrusion.  We select the ngons and "inset face" to eye and get immediate improvement, as the edge vertices' normals now interpolate along right angles to the edge, at a regular distance:

[image]

Except for some artifacts where the curvature is tight, creating overlap on our inset.  We could inset less, or we could live with slightly uneven interpolation by smoothing that out.  I'll use Loop Tools addon's (bundled with Blender) Relax operation to smooth it out:

[image]

What we've done is create a "holding loop" to hold the interpolation of normals across a consistent distance, in the proper direction.

Artifacts are gone.  Smooth shading is as good as it will ever be.  We have great big ngons, but they're fine, because they're planar with their neighbors.  (If we ever want to subdivide, we may need to care about the concavity and holding the holding edge itself.  If we want to render someplace else, we may want to triangulate to get consistent interpolation of UV.)

Our goal with topology is, first and foremost, making a good render.  Our secondary goals are to preserve editability and to improve performance, both goals best served by using as few vertices as possible.  Sometimes, people mistake the guidelines of topology-- all quads, etc-- with the goals themselves.  We could potentially make this ngon all quad.  But doing so would not change the render whatsoever, and it would increase the vertex count.  For what we're doing, an ngon is the best topology.

Does it bevel okay?  Yeah, just fine:

[image]

The main thing with the bevel is, do the bevelled faces follow the edge flow we want, rather than changing direction?  The other thing is, for relative bevel depth types, are the bevelled faces consistent sizes?  And because of the inset faces operation, those things are both true.

What about when we start making holes?  The rules don't change.  We hold the normals, and we don't care about faces that are planar with their neighbors:

[image]

We've got to cut those ngons a little bit, because faces can't have holes, but we just try to minimize concavity and the rest is fine.  For the goals you've stated, at least.